# Teradata timestamp with time zone conversion to timestamp(0)

Tags: timezone, teradata

I want to calculate two timestamps difference in Minutes. one with timestamp(0) startdttm and another one is timestamp(0) with time zone enddttm(converted from GMT to local time zone so its data types is timestamp(0) with time zone) subtraction is not working properly for some rows.
So I want to convert enddttm to timestamp(0). Let me know how to convert timestamp(0) with time zone data type to timestamp(0). Timestamp(0) with time zone values and after conversion to timestamp(0) value should be same.

employee_no        startdttm             enddttm_gmt           TIMEZONE     enddttm_local         (startdttm-endttm_local) Mins
14697         3/12/2021 22:06:34    3/13/2021 06:04:30   Pacific  3/12/2021 22:04:30        -1438

employee_no        startdttm             enddttm_gmt           TIMEZONE     enddttm_local         (startdttm-endttm_local)Mins
14690   3/3/2021 14:18:07   3/3/2021 22:19:08       Pacific     3/3/2021 14:19:08        -1

Comment: Can you show example data and expected result? Did you try to cast startdttm to a timestamp with tome zone?

Comment: Issue with first row.
employee_no        startdttm          enddttm_gmt           TIMEZONE     enddttm_local         (startdttm-endttm_loca) Mins
14690       3/12/2021 22:06:34 3/13/2021 06:04:30  Pacific  3/12/2021 22:04:30     -1438

employee_no        startdttm          enddttm_gmt           TIMEZONE     enddttm_local         (startdttm-endttm_loca) Mins
14697 3/3/2021 14:18:07 3/3/2021 22:19:08     Pacific     3/3/2021 14:19:08      -1
cast(CAST(enddttm_local  AS FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MI:SS') AS CHAR(19)) B
cast(B  as TIMESTAMP(0)  format'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS' ) c --getting error

Comment: cast(CAST(enddttm_local  AS FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MI:SS') AS CHAR(19)) B
cast(B  as TIMESTAMP(0)  format'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS' ) c
I have converted enddttm_local  to char(19) but while converting char(19) to timestamp(0) getting error.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the example? In comments it's hardly readable

Comment: In your cast to c the format needs a 'B', `format'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MI:SS' ` instead of `format'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS' `. *not working properly for some rows*: your dates are around the date when DST added one hour, is the calculation wrong by 60 minutes?

Comment: Updated question. Can we convert time zone datatype into timestamp(0) directly?.

Comment: You can `cast(ts_with_tz as timestamp(0))`, but this happens automatically when you got timestamps with and without time zone.